# How to prove $\||A|\|_2 \le \sqrt{n} \|A \|_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

> How can we prove
>   $$
> \||A|\|_2 \le \sqrt{n} \|A \|_2$$ for any $A \in {\bf C}^{m\times n}$ with $m\ge n$ ?

Comment: What do you mean with the notation $\| |A| \|_2$? Do you mean $\| A \|_1$?

Comment: No, it's the 2-norm of the absolute value of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\||A|\|_2 
&= \sup_{\|x\|_2 \le 1} \||A|x\|_2 \quad \mbox{(by definition of $\|\cdot\|_2$ for matrices)} \\ 
&= \sup_{\|x\|_2 \le 1} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m ||A_i|^Tx |^2} \quad \mbox{($A_i^T$ is $i$-th row of $A$)} \\
&\le \sup_{\|x\|_2 \le 1} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m \|A_i\|_2^2\|x\|_2^2} \quad \mbox{(by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality)} \\
&\le \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m \|A_i\|_2^2} \\
&= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n |A_{ij}|^2} \\
&= \sqrt{\mbox{trace}(A^*A)} \\
&= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^r \sigma_i^2} \quad \mbox{(by properties of trace, $\sigma_i$ is singular value of $A$)} \\
&\le \sqrt{r} \, \sigma_{\max} \quad \mbox{($\sigma_{\max}$ is maximum singular value of $A$)} \\
&= \sqrt{r} \, \|A\|_2, \quad \mbox{(follows from definition of $\sigma_{\max}$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$)}
\end{align}
where $r$ is the rank of $A$, which in this case satisfies $r \le n$.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? Or are you interested in the step $\|A\|_F \le \sqrt{r} \|A\|_2$?

Comment: Yes, I think that proves what I asked. I have the following questions:

1. Why $\| x \| \le 1$ ?
2. Should it be $x_i$ everywhere?
3. A_i^T represents the columns of A right?
4. How do you go from 3 to 4, (I mean from the equality to the inequality)?
5. I would appreciate if you can develop $\|A\|_F \le sqrt(r) \|A\|_2$...

Comment: Ok, I will add notes to the answer to clarify these.

Comment: That should do it. I hope it is clear.

Comment: Excellent! Now it's very clear!

Comment: Cool, don't forget to mark the question as answered.